# Rotate the segment by quaternion - how to find actual segment's end position?

Tags: 3d, quaternions

I have an segment from `[0,0,0]` to `[0,1,0]` (left-handed coordinate system, with Y axis up) which is non-rotated. The rotation is described as quaternion (`[w,x,y,z] = [1,0,0,0]` for non-rotated).

Then, I rotate my segment via some normalized quaternion `Q = [w1,x1,y1,z1]` by the pivot of `[0,0,0]`. **How to calculate the position of the segment's end now?**

If I changed the pivot to `[0,0.5,0]`, **how would that change the formula?**

edit:
because of comment, I clarify what I meant by "pivot" and how the position of the start/end of the segment changes because of rotation (for 2d scenario, but 3d is analogical):
[image]

Comment: I'm kind of unsure what you mean by a pivot, here. Rotations have axes: how is the pivot related to the axis?

Comment: @rschwieb By pivot I mean the origin of the rotation - I guess it's the same as "fixed point" (that point would stay "at place" after rotation).

Comment: ... but an entire *line* is fixed by a rotation, not just a point...

Comment: @rschwieb I don't understand - what do you mean the "line is fixed by rotation"? Take an example of how rotations and pivots work in 3d software - you pick a pivot (usually the center of the object, but not always) and apply the rotation for each mesh vertex around that pivot. The pivot itself is the only point that would not change position after rotation (around itself). Or, I guess you can treat pivot as some "local `[0,0,0]` coordinate system".

Comment: Every rotation in $3$-space fixes an entire *line*. It sounds like a pivot is a distinguished point on the axis, maybe one which you use to erect a system of coordinates with an origin there.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry but I still don't understand what you mean by that "fixing line" phrase. Also, I cannot explain the pivot clearer so it's hard for me to agree or disagree on your second statement.

Comment: "the rotation fixes a line" means "the rotation does not change the position of any point on the line."

Comment: Have you ever heard of the axis of rotation? Here's another example: do you believe that the geographic north and south poles change position with Earth's rotation? (They probably do slightly, but I'm idealizing the picture, here.)

Comment: @rschwieb try to rotate the pencil (segment) around your finger (the pivot) and see how the points on the pencil change their position. Or run 3d software (Blender for the best - you can directly paste the segment position as I described and rotation as quaternion and you will see that points DO change their position and how changing the axis affects it). I guess that the axis of rotation (which does not change during rotation) and segment start/end (which do change during rotation - and I was talking about that) were mislead in our discussion. On my segment only the pivot point stays "fixed".

Comment: OK, so your definition of "pivot" is where your chosen segment intersects the axis of rotation. That's all I needed to know. Now I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quaternions (working by conjugation alone) can only represent rotations whose axes pass through the origin. (The origin is always fixed since $q0q^{-1}=0$.)

You can translate rotations off the origin by using the addition operation of quaternions.

The first step would be to translate the "pivot" to the origin, then you would apply the rotation, and then you would translate it back from whence it came.

$x\mapsto q(x-0.5j)q^{-1}+0.5j$

So if $T$ represents the translation of the origin to $0.5j$, then the original rotation $R$ changes to $TRT^{-1}$ to accommodate the shift.

Comment: Thanks :) And I'm glad that we finally understood each other about the origin :) I might not be precise from the beginning.

Comment: @PolGraphic It's OK: successfully pulling off communication in these situations is an essential part of communicating with mathematics (especially between disciplines!) :)